# Clean installed Windows 8.1 then O.S crashed with missing operating System

Tags: windows-8

My machine (if it is relevant at all) is an Inspiron 7537 with a Crucial MX300 SSD (swapped out the HDD).

Yesterday I fresh-installed Windows 8.1 using a USB key. It worked fine and I installed the following (perhaps one of the apps conflicted with my files?):

```
-League of Legends
-Eclipse
-Java JDK 8.11 
-Java to use the Nvidia detection tools for drivers
-Dell tool to download the missing drivers
-Missing drivers
-SeaTool for windows because of some errors
-Nvidia tool for overclocking ( had to check temperature of the gpu)
-HWDmonitor ( for monitoring CPU temperature)
-Google chrome
```

Now, everything worked fine last night, shut off the computer, etc... This morning, I wake up go on my laptop, watch a movie and this happens:

First series of events:

1. BSOD with error "KERNEL_INPAGE_ERROR"
2. computer restarts
3. After dell screen I see this message " operating system missing"
4. Restart my computer
5. Windows goes into automatic repair mode
6. computer opens fine and I can log into my desktop

Second series of events:

1. I "googled" the error and saw that I should maybe run CHKDSK /r which I did in Admin mode in CMD
2. It only scanned on restart, which I did
3. I then opened my computer and I couldn't access the "PC settings" (it would minimize automatically) and so I ran this command:

   ```
   powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register
   $EnvystemRoot\ImmersiveControlPanel\AppxManifest.xm
   ```

PC setting is working again, great! I go on with watching my movie, and the computer shuts down again... Though now I'm getting a weird error:

> Windows won't start because of missing files
>
> Boot\BCD
> File: c:\system32\winload.exe
> Error code: 0xc0000001

I believe those were it. I had to re-install my O.S. I'm just worried it'll pull the same thing on me again, is there a way to pinpoint what might have happened? it worries me that my new SSD might be corrupted or whatnot.

Answer (score -1):

I thought the laptop is already equipped with Windows 8.1. It might be technical failure. Or one of the commands actually deleted the boot files. Remember, running codes in CMD is risky especially if you're not experienced. Make sure the OS in the USB is a genuine Windows OS. If you can't access the OS, go back to the HDD included with the laptop. And, yes. Your SSD might be corrupted. Did you download all the latest drivers for your laptop?

Comment: 1) Yeah downloaded all the drivers , used the dell tool for that.

Comment: Jeez... I can't edit. 2) I can't go back to the HDD it died... Though I did try the CHKDSK command and it found nothing, same for the seaTool ( from Seagate I think) 3) I believe the version is genuine but that key is rather old. 4) might have been the powershell script... who knows :/

Comment: I seriously don't know why it would happen. The last time it happened to me turned out that my HDD is corrupting. Sorry for the late reply. I hope everything is sorted out!